# What is the second, bearded form of the keeper character about?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

Needing four more hard mode unlocks (Lilith: boss rush, Hush | Keeper: The Lamb, Mega Satan ) my character keeper has now a new visual:

[image]

I can't find any info on the wikis or the net besides that the sprite has been found by data miners but noth that what it does once I have unlocked it as a playable visual for the keeper character. Does someone know how it changes the character or where the unlock is described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/4cuzb5/aprils_fool_keeper_what_is_this/), the Keeper temporarily has that new sprite for April Fools Day. The comments on the thread indicate that only the sprite is different, and the character is otherwise the same.

Comment: That sprite was also the temporary one used to throw the dataminers off while the [ARG](https://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/3ss8oo/the_afterbirth_arg_a_stepbystep_summary/) was unfolding.